# PI must not start with xml

Tags: java, android, xml

```
    //Initialize soap request 

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    //Use this to add parameters
    request.addProperty("agentcode",agentCode);
    request.addProperty("pincode",agentCodePin);
    request.addProperty("appversion",appversion);
    request.addProperty("deviceid",deviceid);
    request.addProperty("latitude",latitude);
    request.addProperty("longitude",longitude);

  //Declare the version of the SOAP request
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    envelope.dotNet = true;

    try {

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        //this is the actual part that will call the web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;


        if(result != null)
        {

             DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
             factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

             DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

             InputSource is = new InputSource();
             is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader( result.toString()));

             org.w3c.dom.Document doc = builder.parse(is);

             doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            //Get Node List
             NodeList nlist = doc.getElementsByTagName("paypoint");
            //Get node
             Node nNode = (Node) nlist.item(0);

            if (nNode.getType(0) == Node.ELEMENT)
            {
                //get element
                Element elt = (Element) nNode; 

                // Get token
                this.token = elt.getElementsByTagName("token").item(0).getTextContent();
                // Get flag
                this.flag = elt.getElementsByTagName("statusCode").item(0).getTextContent();
                // Get agent name
                this.agentName = elt.getElementsByTagName("fullname").item(0).getTextContent();
            }

            }
          } catch (Exception e)
          {
                throw e;
          }

        return this.flag;
```

I am having problem at this line: is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader( result.toString()));

the error is : PI must not start with xml ( portion: unknown xml@1:30 in java.io.stringReader@40579f48)

My Xml file look like this:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><paypoint> <token>PkSMTTulAndNmM9R4Vmi+QRWtChW/Xs61sPERoTpB5eEgRfrQKUi6r2rqLQNusvJpVJ1oZBc8Z0=</token>   <statusCode>1</statusCode><statusText>VALID USER</statusText><fullname>Dao    Lacina</fullname><walletbalance>2000.00</walletbalance></paypoint>
```

Any help

Answer (score 4):

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>` must be the first line of your XML Document. Could you try instead :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<paypoint> 
<token>PkSMTTulAndNmM9R4Vmi+QRWtChW/Xs61sPERoTpB5eEgRfrQKUi6r2rqLQNusvJpVJ1oZBc8Z0=</token>   
<statusCode>1</statusCode>
<statusText>VALID USER</statusText>
<fullname>Dao    Lacina</fullname>
<walletbalance>2000.00</walletbalance>
</paypoint>
</string>
```

Comment: i will ask the sys admin to alter it for me

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is not `well-formed`. The first line HAVE TO be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

so your XML should start with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
```

See Wiki on [well-formed document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document)

Answer (score 1):

this was happening to me with android in eclipse ... solved it by removing the 3 byte utf-8 bom from the start of the file.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem but I figured out that it is not a fault of not well formed XML document ,Sometimes it would be that problem but this time, it is due by not using correct output stream that the server is using to send the data to the client side ...
 my server-side code is this :

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream((OutputStream) response.getOutputStream());
```

but my client side code is :

```
InputStream is =(InputStream) httpConnection.openDataInputStream();
```

so finally I changed the streams to match each other ,then the problem also solved ...
I still don't understand why is it happens when those streams are different even the streams are inherited by the same InputStream

(I used this for J2ME sdk 3.0.5)